# Advice for recovering a lost psd file in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I had a psd file unexpectedly go missing. Due to a large amount of data processing in my Macbook Air photoshop shut down. I did not realize the file went missing until a few days later. It had been saved multiple times before. I also recently emptied my trash bin. Any suggestions for finding it?

THANKYOU!

Comment: Without a back up, you are out of luck.

Comment: If the file was accidentally removed, it is possible to use file recovery software to get it back... for a while. If you wait too long, it won't be possible anymore. Emptying the trashcan is not exactly like shredding a file. It's more like forgetting where you put it. But over time it is replaced by data.